# Building with rpmbuild under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, build, rpm, yum, rpmbuild

I need to build yum with a patch under Ubuntu 10.4 (reason being that i need a yum with chroot support for my vserver instance)

Since yum src for ubuntu where not avaliable (3rd party repos) i downloaded the source off the official repos and the patch off the linux-vserver.

However, when i try to build it with

```
rpmbuild -ba yum.spec
```

It fails with

```
error: Failed build dependencies:
    python is needed by yum-3.2.22-0.src
    gettext is needed by yum-3.2.22-0.src
    intltool is needed by yum-3.2.22-0.src
```

Now i have all of these installed and i have no idea how to resolve this since i don't go rebuilding my stuff everyday.

Regards,
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to enter the right deb-src repos to your yum list, download the source with apt-get source yum and apply the patch. Finally build the package with dpkg-buildpackage.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that rpmbuild is trying to resolve the dependencies using RPM's own database of installed packages - which is not the same thing as apt-get's database.  apt-get knows those things are installed, but rpm doesn't.

Since you're sure you have these things installed, I'd suggest editing yum.spec and removing them from the BuildRequires line.

Comment: Yes. It does indeed start building. And then the errors start. 


install -m 644 yum.8 /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/yum-3.2.22-0.i386/usr/share/man/man8/yum.8
install: cannot create regular file `/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/yum-3.2.22-0.i386/usr/share/man/man8/yum.8': No such file or directory