# missing node dependency when building an rpm package from nodejs project

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build an rpm package from nodejs project on ubuntu 18.04, I'm using [speculate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speculate) to generate [menlolab-runner.spec](https://pastebin.com/ZQNdK5gj) and systemd files. But when I run `rpmbuild -bb ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/menlolab-runner.spec` I get missing dependancy error:

```
error: Failed build dependencies:
        nodejs is needed by menlolab-runner-0.1.4-1.x86_64
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5269640/11511781) to similar question, I need to add right deb-src repos to yum list, I don't know how to go about doing that. Here's my [package.json](https://pastebin.com/qCWZpdub) if it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to build an rpm package from nodejs project on ubuntu 18.04

ubuntu is `deb` based, not `rpm` based, so building an `rpm` on a `deb` based system is bound to cause you trouble...

`rpmbuild` is complaining because he needs `nodejs` to be installed on your system to allow building this spec file (you will find `BuildRequires: nodejs` in your spec file).

Although nodejs is probably installed on your system by `dpkg`, `rpm` does not know about it because `rpm` has its own database where it stores the information of what package is installed.

You could try using the `--nodeps` flag to tell `rpmbuild` to ignore your build dependencies, but again I don't think it to be a good idea to build `rpm` files on a `deb`-based system.

Comment: After a while I've just build the rpm in docker - centos 7, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: if my answer helped you solve your problem, consider accepting it. This shows to other people also that this question is solved.